# Format MongoDB Query output

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I'm currently running a MongoDB instance to save collected tweets within a geo-box in realtime. With that, I want to generate a heatmap to show where the most tweets were sent in Amsterdam. To do that I have to query the geo line only. That works with the following line of code:

```
db.testtweets.find({"geo": { "$ne": null } }, { "geo": 1 });
```

Unfortunately, this returns more info then the Google Maps API needs. Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56fea2cf206e3712f3d1a9bb"), "geo" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 52.3746373, 4.85773855 ] } }
```

What I want as output:

```
52.3746373, 4.85773855
```

I'm quite new to MongoDB, so would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get using [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is:

```
db.testtweets.find(
    { "geo": { "$ne": null } }, 
    { "geo.coordinates": 1, "_id": 0 }
)
```

which produces:

```
{ "geo" : { "coordinates" : [ 52.3746373, 4.85773855 ] } }
```

From there you use client-side processing to return the "coordinates" array field value.

---

You can also use the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method to do this. All you will need is [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents.

```
db.testtweets.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { "geo": { "$ne": null } } }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "coordinates": "$geo.coordinates", 
        "_id": 0 
    }}
]);
```

which yields something like:

```
{ "coordinates" : [ 52.3746373, 4.85773855 ] }
```

Translation in PHP gives:

```
db.testtweets.aggregate(array( 
    array("$match" => array("geo" => array( "$ne" => null)), 
    array("$project" => array( 
        "coordinates" => "$geo.coordinates", 
        "_id" => 0 
    ))
));
```

Comment: Thanks, it indeed gives the output you mentioned. Is there any way it will only output the numbers 52.3746373, 4.85773855?